# How to change filepicker open button text as send in xamarin forms UWP?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

As i have using cross file picker for pick a file from local in Xamarin forms UWP. I tried to change the button text from open to send in file dialog window. But i can't change that.
Please check the attached image,

[image: [1]:]

My requirement is need to change the open text as send. Please let me know if you have any solution for this.

Comment: You need to do this by using Native Code. Create a dependency service Use `FileOpenPicker` and in that set `CommitButtonText` to your liking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to change filepicker open button text as send in xamarin forms UWP?

[`Xamarin.Essentials.FilePicker`](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/main/Xamarin.Essentials/FilePicker/FilePicker.uwp.cs) has not supported to edit commit button text. For your requirement, we suggest you use [dependency service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to make the custom picker and edit
[`CommitButtonText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker.commitbuttontext?view=winrt-19041) in the UWP client project.

```
FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();
picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
picker.CommitButtonText = "Fine";
var file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks @Nico Zhu - MSFT